# temporarily redirect a nuget package in a solution to local project

Tags: nuget

I have two VS 2013 projects in separate solutions, one of which uses NuGet to manage/consume the other.

I need to change the second project and want to test it in the first one, but I can't publish to our local NuGet repository, in case someone accidentally uses it.  Now that I think of it, I don't have publish rights anyway.

I'd like to temporarily, locally redirect the reference to this second, modified project in the first one.  How best can I do that, ideally with as little disruption and cleanup when testing is done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a local directory as a NuGet source.
2. Create a package of the project you want to test and copy it to this directory in step 1
3. Install the new package from NuGet Package Manager and test.

This way you dont have to change project refs etc.